# How can add a line break using tag '<br/>' Under product picture in woocommerce

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I want to put a row "br /" under the picture of the simple products on the categories page.
Have two types of products in the shop, simple and with variations.
Products with variations have a row with filters, simples products do not. I want to alighn the visualization of the two types of products. . I'm trying with this code:

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_shop_loop_item_title', 'shop_loop_item_title', 9 );
function shop_loop_item_title($_product) {

foreach ( $order->get_items() as $item ) {
       
        $product = $item->get_product();

        if( $product->is_type('simple') ){
            echo "<div>
        <h1><br /></h1>
      </div>";
            
        } else {
        
            // is not simple
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can align them equally by using CSS instead of this code. Give appropriate line-height to fix it. I have done this for my client's website in which the names of products have different lengths. Because of that products become unequal. So I gave equal line-height of 3 and they become aligned perfectly.
[see this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gpeVp.png)